# How to open search interface over BottomNavigationView's fragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, bottomnavigationview, android-search, android-bottomnav

I want to implement an interface having BottomNavigationView where clicking on the top search bar opens the next interface shown in figure 2. I have implemented BottomNavigationView. But unable to do that above said.

[image]

[image]

Here is the code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.home_bottom_nav_view);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home_recent_menu_id);
        

        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                Fragment selectedFragment = new RecentFragment();

                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.home_contact_menu_id:
                        selectedFragment = new ContactFragment();
                        break;

                    case R.id.home_recent_menu_id:
                        selectedFragment = new RecentFragment();
                        break;

                    case R.id.home_status_menu_id:
                        selectedFragment = new StatusFragment();
                        break;

                }

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.home_fragment_container_lyt_id, selectedFragment).commit();
                return true;

            }
        });


    }


}
```

Home Activity XML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/home_search_view_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_fragment_container_lyt_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/home_search_view_id"
        android:layout_above="@+id/home_bottom_nav_view"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/home_bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. create a `BottomNavigationFragment` which is going to contain `ViewPager2` with `BottomNavigationView` and that view pager will contain `[favourite, recent and contacts ]` fragments
2. create a `SearchFragment` which will be used for searching purpose
3. create a navigation graph  which will contain `[BottomNavigationFragment and SearchFragment]` when user clicks on search view navigate him to `SearchFragment`

you can also set animation using Navigation Component lib

//adapter for `ViewPager2` vp2 in `BottomNavigationFragment`
[image]

lets say your `SearchView` is in `favourite` fragment onClick or onFocus of that

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.toSearchFragment)
```

you will land in Search fragment

Comment: Can you please show me any link with example?

Comment: I have updated the answer let me know in which part u need link to understand more

Comment: I have updated my question. Please tell me what to do.

Comment: 1. instead of Activity use Fragment and place xml in that fragment "BottomNavigationFragment" 2.change frame layout with ViewPager2 and FragmentStatePageAdapter 3. create another fragment called search fragment 4. now in activity use NavigationComponentLib from google

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DI0NIk-7cz8&list=PLSrm9z4zp4mHilvsfUM3jeCYFV3fTAS3J watch this playlist u will have better understanding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240038/discussion-between-bhaskar-jyoti-dutta-and-abhijith-mogaveera).